# Passing the parameter 'name' in php form handling

Tags: php, html

In my database i have created a table named iso(2 columns- name of ISO certificate and the code) and by the code below, I am trying to print the names of all the certificates as submit type buttons(clickable). But I am not able to pass that which button was passed to the next file. Please help. Thanks!

```
     <?php 
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dyna");
// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
         }

          $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM iso");
          ?>

  <form method="post" action="http://localhost/junk.php/">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       { ?>
       <input type="submit" name="<?php $row['Code'] ?>" class="login login-submit" value="<?php echo $row['Value'] ?>" >
        <?php } ?>
    <?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
  </form>
```

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: <?php echo $row['Value'].'_'.$row['Code'] ?> concatenate the code with value  with delimiter.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, you should accept it.

Comment: mark an answer as correct...

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<button>` element named `cert`, to pass your certificate code as a value, but show the name certificate as the button name:

```
<button name="cert" value="<?php echo $row['Code']; ?>" type="submit"><?php echo $row['Value']; ?></button>
```

Then in your `junk.php`, use the POST argument `cert` to determine which button was pressed based on your certificate code:

```
if (isset($_POST['cert']))
{
    $cert_code= $_POST['cert'];
    // do something with $cert_code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want both value and code means .concatenate the `code` with value with delimiter.

```
<input type="submit" name="certificate" class="login login-submit" value="<?php echo $row['Value'].'_'.$row['Code'] ?>" >

       $ss = explode('_',$_POST['certificate']);

       echo  $ss[0];  //value
       echo $ss[1];   //code
```

Comment: I am sure he doesn't want a button named something like `Certificate name_CRT-AB-3535` and just wants `Certificate name`. And what happens, if the value has underscores?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can use `<?= $var ?>` or `<?= "test" ?>` to print to avoid using `<?php echo...`.

So, if I understood your question, you cannot print correctly the `$row` values to the `<input>` tag.

You can debug what is receiving your query why doing `var_dump($row);` at any part of the `while` part. So if you are receiving correctly the array, you will see which keys it have.

And one more thing, replace your `mysqli_fetch_array` by `mysqli_fetch_assoc` because the first one assign the name of the columns **but** it adds numeric keys to the `$row` array too.

To understand better, read [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but probably because you didn't answer the question and just mentioned other mistakes.

Comment: I wrote quote "if I understood your question, you cannot print correctly the `$row` values to the `<input>` tag." so, why downvote me people ? Insted of downvoting, tell me what is he asking... Thanks for the comment @gre_gor

Comment: Changing echo style and mysql fetch types doesn't solve the OP's problem.  They are a matter of personal taste not a mistake.  You didn't answer the question.

Comment: @Progrock how could I answer the question if I am asking if I did understand... read comments pls...

Comment: I read all the comments, if you don't understand the question, ask the OP to clarify before answering.

Comment: I didnt have the points needed for that... I anyway wanted to help him